# Scala: public getter with private setter?

Tags: scala

How can I make a field that has a public getter but the setter is private, in Scala?

EDIT: too bad there is no one-liner way to do this like there is in Groovy.  Those solutions are all pretty clunky looking.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
class Foo {
  private var _value: Int = 0
  def value = _value
}
```

Comment: One may prefer `class Foo(private var _value : Int) { def value = _value }`.

Comment: Possibly, although that exposes `_value` as a named parameter, which may not me desirable.

Comment: Right, my version creates a constructor with that parameter.

Answer (score 11):

```
class ExplicitProperty {
   private[this] var s: Int = _
   def size = s
   private def size_=(x: Int) {
      s = x
   }
}
```